# Showing $f(x,y)$ is continuous.

Tags: analysis, continuity

I have the following statement which I want to prove or disprove. To me $f(a,y)$ and $f(b,y)$ seems completely different function, in general, where $a,b$ are constants. I really don't expect this statement to be true, but I couldn't find any counterexample though. Thank you!

Here is the statement.

Let $f\in \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for each $a\in \mathbb{R}$, $f(a,y)$ is continuously differentiable in $y.$ and for each $b,$ $f(x,b)$ is continuously differentiable in $x.$

Comment: For clarification: what is it that you want to prove? It seems like you are providing just a hypothesis. Or do you want an example of a function that has the property you mentioned?

Comment: When the partial derivative are continuous then we have an even stronger result which is $f$ differentiable. And differentiability implies continuity. Also if just the partial derivative exists there are counter examples showing $f$ could be non-continuous. I think also that if they are locally bounded, f is locally continuous.

Comment: An interesting question could be, is there a simplified proof that continuous partial derivatives implies $f$ continuous which somehow bypass proving differentiability ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a counterexample

$$f(x)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$$

it's not continuous at $0$, however it satisfies in the condition that I told.

Comment: Yes, this is a good counter example. In fact if you set $f(0,0)=0$ just to avoid issue defining $f(0,y)=0$ then $\frac{d}{dy}[f(a,y)]\neq\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,y)$ for $a=0$. Since these are not a partial derivatives, it's ok that $f$ is not differentiable even under the hypothesis of continuity of these derivatives.